# Get current config in Jenkins DSL

Tags: jenkins-job-dsl

I want to access the config of the currently executing seed job from within my DSL script.

For example, I want to use the same SCM settings as my seed job for the jobs that I am creating.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in DSL way to do that. You need to have a look at the [Jenkins API](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/). To obtain the SCM settings of the currently executing job, do this:

```
hudson.model.Executor executor = hudson.model.Executor.currentExecutor()
hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild build = executor.currentExecutable
hudson.model.FreeStyleProject project = build.project
hudson.scm.SCM scm = project.scm
```

Comment: is there any way in the jenkins test harness to do this? I want to validate the config the job dsl is writing before actually running it on jenkins. does the multibranchPipelineJob() or other job dsl functions output the config they write or anything like that?